# Groupby in MongoTemplate returning empty fields

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a collection with fields `id, a-int, b-int, c-int, total-int`. I am trying to get `a, b, c, total` but I end up getting just the sum of `total` and rest of the field values are `0, 0, 0`. How do I fix this? Expected result from the data sample below `10, 20, 30, 300`

Thanks

Data sample

```
id,   a,  b,  c, total
xid, 10, 20, 30, 100
xid, 10, 20, 30, 200


GroupBy groupBy = GroupBy.key("{a : 1, b : 1, c : 1}")
  .initialDocument("{ total: 0 }")
  .reduceFunction("function(obj, result) { result.total += obj.total; }");

GroupByResults<Grouped> results = mongoTemplate.group(Criteria.where("id").is(id),
TABLE, groupBy, Grouped.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the result I think you wanted using the following:

```
GroupBy groupBy = GroupBy.key("a", "b", "c")
                         .initialDocument("{ total: 0 }")
                         .reduceFunction("function(obj, result) { " +
                                         "  result.a = obj.a; " +
                                         "  result.b = obj.b; " +
                                         "  result.c = obj.c; " +
                                         "  result.total += obj.total; " +
                                         "}");
```

Note that what you need to do is tell the reduce function what to put into the a, b, and c fields as well as the total field.

This gave me a raw output of:

```
{ "a" : 10.0 , "b" : 20.0 , "c" : 30.0 , "total" : 300.0}
```

Since you haven't included the Grouped class, I'm not sure if this maps exactly into the object that you wanted, but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I do have a Group class to map it. Never too late for a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: what if
id,   a,  b,  c, total
xid, 10, 20, 30, 100
xid, 10, 20, 30, 200
xid, 10, 10, 30, 300
xid, 10, 30, 30, 400

i need like 

{ "a" : 10.0 , "b" : 20.0 , "c" : 30.0 , "total" : 300.0}
{ "a" : 10.0 , "b" : 10.0 , "c" : 30.0 , "total" : 300.0}
{ "a" : 10.0 , "b" : 30.0 , "c" : 30.0 , "total" : 300.0}