# Mongo DB Aggregates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm stuck in a problem of aggregates in mongoDB. The data structure that I'm dealing with is like this :-

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f16fe11d1e2d32371072aa0"),
        "body" : " \nHi Kate, per our discussion on yesterday about the $15.00 f
lat fee on Tom's \nand Mark's deals, here is Bloomberg's response.  Please pass
this info to all \nof our traders.  Please let me know what the response is from
 them.\n\nThanks\n\n\n---------------------- Forwarded by Evelyn Metoyer/Corp/En
ron on 04/17/2001 \n02:34 PM ---------------------------\n\n\n\"PAUL CALLAHAN, B
LOOMBERG/ NEW YORK\" <PCALLAHAN2@bloomberg.net> on 04/17/2001 \n02:28:57 PM\nTo:
 Evelyn.Metoyer@enron.com\ncc:  \n\nSubject: Commission\n\n\nEvelyn, as of April
 16, 2001 our charge for Spot trades is a flat fee of\n$15/trade.\n\n\n",
        "filename" : "3272.",
        "headers" : {
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding" : "7bit",
                "Content-Type" : "text/plain; charset=us-ascii",
                "Date" : ISODate("2001-04-17T14:33:00Z"),
                "From" : "evelyn.metoyer@enron.com",
                "Message-ID" : "<33504483.1075841847839.JavaMail.evans@thyme>",
                "Mime-Version" : "1.0",
                "Subject" : "Commission for Bloomberg",
                "To" : [
                        "kate.symes@enron.com"
                ],
                "X-FileName" : "kate symes 6-27-02.nsf",
                "X-Folder" : "\\kate symes 6-27-02\\Notes Folders\\Discussion th
reads",
                "X-From" : "Evelyn Metoyer",
                "X-Origin" : "SYMES-K",
                "X-To" : "Kate Symes",
                "X-bcc" : "",
                "X-cc" : ""
        },
        "mailbox" : "symes-k",
        "subFolder" : "discussion_threads"
}
```

There are 120477 records in the database. I'm supposed to find out the pair of people who tend to communicate most (and 2nd most) with each other. The query that I've written is as follows:

```
db.messages.aggregate([{$project:{From:"$headers.From",To:"$headers.To",_id:0}
},{$unwind:"$headers.To"},{$group:{_id:{From:"$From",To:"$To"},number:{$sum:1}}}
,{$limit:3},{$sort:{number:-1}}]);
```

but it somehow does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: Try looking at this example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302544/groupby-in-mongotemplate-returning-empty-fields

Comment: I mean the query does not give me the number of people who communicate the most.

Comment: Try changing `$unwind:"$headers.To"` to `$unwind:"$To"`

Comment: Dear fourth eye..it worked :D..here is the final query..thanks for all the help..> db.messages.aggregate([{$project:{"headers.From":1,"headers.To":1,_id:0}},{$u
wind:"$headers.To"},{$group:{_id:{From:"$headers.From",To:"$headers.To"},number
{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{number:-1}},{$limit:3}]);

Comment: this just gives you top 3 for a particular combination of "from-to" - shouldn't you be adding that to all the to-from that have the same names?  if to:a from:b is 10 and from:b to:a is 5 then you have 15 communications between those two, not 10.